# Need to update request values in saved fiddler sessions

Tags: fiddler

I need to update the response value of my saved fiddler session.Suppose i have a saved a fiddler session of any service which has 10-20 methods in it.
Now I want to update the request value(e.g hostname) in my saved fiddler session and want to replay it sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily write script that modifies any aspect of Sessions. Click Rules > Customize Rules. Inside the `Handlers` class add a new block like e.g.

```
    public static ContextAction("Set MIME...")
    function dosetmime(oS: Session[])
    {
        var s = FiddlerObject.prompt("Enter the Content-Type value", "image/jpeg", "Set MIME");
        for (var i: int=0; i<oS.Length; i++)
        {
            oS[i].oResponse["Content-Type"] = s;            
        }
    }
```

Save the script and you now have a new Context Menu command "Set MIME" that changes the response `Content-Type` header of each selected Session.